# Angularjs - Change value based on siblings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have multiple `dropdown select`s which will decide on specific input values

The HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="chosenitem" style="width:100%;" ng-change="changedValue(i,$index)" >
        <option value="" disabled selected>choose item</option>
        <option ng-repeat="me in stuffs">{{me.item}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="inputattr[i]"  placeholder="attribute">
</div>
```

The controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.stuffs = [
    {item:'car', attribute:'wheels'},
    {item:'plane', attribute:'wings'},
    {item:'boat', attribute:'propeller'}
  ];

  $scope.changedValue = function(i,j){
    $scope.inputattr[i] = $scope.stuffs[j].attribute;
  };
});
```

The problem is `inputattr` is dynamic. I can never get it to work. Here is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lrDPUkVeQOh9qlA9PAKn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GVanAH70oyEEI16Nbf0t

you never actually initialized `inputattr`. there also was an issue with your indexes, which should usually start at `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because `inputattr` is not initialized. Add

```
$scope.inputattr = ['','',''];
```

inside `MainCtrl`. That will do the trick.